# google maps api v3 setMapType issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to change the maptype in google maps from roadmap to satellite when a user clicks on a marker, but I'm getting errors. I've tried:

```
map.setMapTypeId("SATELLITE");
```

or

```
map.setMapTypeId(SATELLITE);
```

or

```
map.setMapTypeId(mapTypeId:Satellite);
```

What am I doing wrong here? This is the documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Comment: "but I'm getting errors" - what errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want:

```
google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
```

which evaluates to `"satellite"` - but you're better off using the API version, in case they ever change the string constant. Full call:

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
```

Comment: Link to the specific documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html